# Lotus domino FTSearch query

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a problem with query in `FTSearch` method. I was using query like `" FIELD fldContractorCode = \"K005152\""` and it was fine but now I need to add one more option to query. And I tried to use:

```
"form= "formcontractor" & FIELD fldContractorCode = "K005152""
"Form = "formcontractor" & FIELD fldContractorCode = "K005152""
"FORM = "formcontractor" & FIELD fldContractorCode = "K005152""
"form= "formcontractor" AND FIELD fldContractorCode = "K005152""
"Form = "formcontractor" AND FIELD fldContractorCode = "K005152""
"FORM = "formcontractor" AND FIELD fldContractorCode = "K005152""
```

But I always get the error that query is not understandable.

How to make this query work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really use FTSearch, then the formula would have to look like:

```
FIELD form ="formcontractor" & FIELD fldContractorCode = "K00515"
```

You need the "FIELD"- Statement in front of every single statement...
A shorter form would be:

```
[form] = "formcontractor" & [fldContractorCode] = "K00515"
```

You could even ommit the ""- signs in FTSearch.

But I would really NOT recommend to use FTSearch as it is always a "contains"- Search (query would also find K00515xxx).

Better use the .search- Method of the NotesDatabase- Class and write it like:

```
db.Search( {Form ="formcontractor" & fldContractorCode = "K00515"}, Nothing, 0 )
```

Then you are SURE to only return the documents that contain EXACTLY the data you search for. And in question of speed it should only be slightly slower.

Comment: db.Search is MUCH slower. I would avoid that at all costs.
Another solution is to use a view lookup, using col.GetDocumentByKey(ket$, True)

Comment: You are of course right, that db.Search is slower, but as long as it is used in a background agent we usually talk about seconds (or a small number of minutes, if the database is REALLY big (100.000 document and more)). Of course you would not want to bother a user with waiting for that result, and of course a GetDocumentByKey will be way faster, but in some cases you simply don't want to (or are not allowed to) create a matching view in the target database...